# How to open new route in same page where having NavigationRail ( Flutter Web )

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

[Screen with NavigationRail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwBiu.png)

I wan to open new route after onDestinationSelected method called in NavigationRail. The problem is when I change route the entire screen change. I can not see NavigationRail on next page.

**UI:**

```
Scaffold(
        body: Row(
      children: [
        Obx(
          () => NavigationRail(
            labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
            destinations: const [
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: Text('Home'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.message),
                label: Text('Chat'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: Text('Profile'),
              ),
            ],
            selectedIndex: controller.selectedIndex.value,
            onDestinationSelected: (value) =>
                controller.onDestinationSelected(value, context),
          ),
        ),
        const VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
        Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: Obx(
              () => Container(
                child: Text(
                  controller.levelText.value,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
```

**onDestinationSelected**

```
 onDestinationSelected(int value, BuildContext context) {
    selectedIndex.value = value;
    levelText.value = getTextAsIndex(value);
    Get.toNamed(Routes.EXPERIMENT);
  }
```